# Only one application working in the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

As I understand of [the guide on scopes](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/beginner2expert-how_to_start.html), I'm supposed to be able to host the application in a DOM element, such as a div (as opposed to hosting it globally by *ng-app* attribute in the *HTML* tag).

It seems to work for the first application but not the other. I have the following example and I expected *AppUno* and *AppDuo* to work, while *AppTri* would fail. The case is, though, that only the first one behaves as expected.

```
<body>
  <div ng-app="AppUno">Uno {{someHolder}}!</div>
  <div ng-app="AppDuo">Duo {{someHolder}}!</div>
  <div ng-app="AppTri">Tri {{someHolder}}!</div>
</body>

var uno = angular.module('AppUno', []);
var duo = angular.module('AppDuo', []);

uno.run(function ($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.someHolder = "Blipp";
});

duo.run(function ($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.someHolder = "Blopp";
});
```

Am I misunderstanding the compartmentalization paradigm? Is it a syntax error that my eyes refuse to see? Anything else?

The output is as follows.

> Uno Blipp!
>   Duo {{someHolder}}!
>   Tri {{someHolder}}!

Comment: @maioman Aha, got it. You might want to post that as a reply so it can be an accepted answer. If you post in a short example and a link or two, it's even better (+1, mate, +1 - I know you want it, hehe).

Comment: Also from the docs it is actually possible to have multiple applications in one html doc BUT: To run multiple applications in an HTML document you must manually bootstrap them using angular.bootstrap instead

Comment: @MikeCheel Please excuse me if I'm confusing the nomenclature here. I though that I **was bootstrapping** by implementing the functions sent into *xxx.run(...)* methods. Was I not?

Comment: take a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap

Comment: The docs say one app per html document (using ng-app directive). When you use ng-app iangular calls the bootstrap method for you I believe. If you wanted to have multiple apps in the same html document you must use angular,bootstrap to manually bootstrap them. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap Notice the ng docs example does NOT use the ng-app directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you can only have one [ng-app](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp) directive;

You could run multiple applications but only one can be bootstrapped with `ng-app` ( for other apps you would need to manually bootstrap them using [angular.bootstrap](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap)).

---

As far as compartmentalization paradigm is concerned there are many way to create child scopes, using you're structure you can consider ng-controller.